# Running a SQL using sqlplus in UNIX?

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

While running the SQL using sqlplus, I dodn't want to dispaly anything on the screen. I am using SPOOL to save the contents to a file. even if I redirect it dispalys connected to SQL, SQL> 1 2 ....
How can I prevent these entries from getting printed?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655018 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress the contents of the SQLplus command in UNIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655018/suppress-the-contents-of-the-sqlplus-command-in-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if everything else fails, you could try

```
sqlplus username/password@database @myscript.sql >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: No. Redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null eliminates everything that is not spooled.

Answer (score 2):

Try the option -silent (or just -s):

```
> sqlplus -s username/password@database
```

Comment: thanks sqlplus -s user/password@instance as sysdba @file.sql  this command is working