# Suppress the contents of the SQLplus command in UNIX?

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

While connecting to db [ oracle] using sqlplus in Unix, I don't want to display the contents like:

```
connected to...
SQL>....
```

How would I remove these display entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probably looking for the option -silent (or just -s):

```
> sqlplus -s username/password@database
```

Comment: Its better to redirect to a file